# Jenkins pipeline - Detect changes of multiple repositories

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a question on Jenkin Pipelines.
I have multiple repositories to setup CI on. All of these repositories should follow the same build step.

My question is how do I enable this behavior. The current Jenkins Pipeline that I have only checks out the repositories but proceeds to build the next stages regardless of changes...

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    triggers {
        pollSCM('H/1 * * * *')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                dir('ABC'){
                    checkout poll: true,
                             scm: [$class: 'GitSCM',
                                  branches: [[name: '**']],
                                  doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                                  extensions: [],
                                  submoduleCfg: [],
                                  userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'an_id1',
                                                       url: 'git@github.com:ABC.git']]]
                }
                dir('DEF'){
                    checkout poll: true,
                             scm: [$class: 'GitSCM',
                                  branches: [[name: '**']],
                                  doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                                  extensions: [],
                                  submoduleCfg: [],
                                  userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'an_id2',
                                                       url: 'git@github.com:DEF.git']]]
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'printenv'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `sh 'printenv'` is always executed. Not when changes are found.
Is there a way to capture the output of the checkout commands and detect if there was a change on a particular branch?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Git Changelog Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Changelog+Plugin)

Get the changes into a string and then check for any changes. This example is from the plugin page:

```
node {
 deleteDir()
 sh """
 git clone git@github.com:jenkinsci/git-changelog-plugin.git .
 """

 def changelogString = gitChangelog returnType: 'STRING',
  from: [type: 'REF', value: 'git-changelog-1.50'],
  to: [type: 'REF', value: 'master'],
  template: """
 <h1> Git Changelog changelog </h1>

<p>
Changelog of Git Changelog.
</p>

{{#tags}}
<h2> {{name}} </h2>
 {{#issues}}
 {{#hasIssue}}
 {{#hasLink}}
<h2> {{name}} <a href="{{link}}">{{issue}}</a> {{title}} </h2>
 {{/hasLink}}
 {{^hasLink}}
<h2> {{name}} {{issue}} {{title}} </h2>
 {{/hasLink}}
 {{/hasIssue}}
 {{^hasIssue}}
<h2> {{name}} </h2>
 {{/hasIssue}}


 {{#commits}}
<a href="https://github.com/tomasbjerre/git-changelog-lib/commit/{{hash}}">{{hash}}</a> {{authorName}} <i>{{commitTime}}</i>
<p>
<h3>{{{messageTitle}}}</h3>

{{#messageBodyItems}}
 <li> {{.}}</li> 
{{/messageBodyItems}}
</p>


 {{/commits}}

 {{/issues}}
{{/tags}}
 """

 currentBuild.description = changelogString
}
```

Other option is to use Web Hooks instead of pooling the SCM, but you will need to change your pipeline for that